# long to wide format in pandas with multiple groups

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataset that is similar in this format:

```
CITY - YEAR - ATTRIBUTE - VALUE
## example:

dallas-2002-crime-100
dallas-2003-crime-101
dallas-2002-population-4000
houston-2002-population-4100
etc....
```

I'm trying to transpose this long to wide format so that each **city+year** value is a row and all the distinct combinations of **attributes** are the columns-names.

Thus this new dataframe would look like:

```
###
city - year - population - crime - median_income- etc....
```

I've looked at the pivot function, but it doesn't seem to support a multi-index for reshaping.  Can someone let me know how to work around transposing?  Additionally, I tried to look at
`pd.pivot_table` but it seems this typically only works with numerical data with sums,means, etc.   Most of my VALUE attributes are actually strings, so I don't seem to be able to use this.

```
### doesn't work - can't use a multindex 
df.pivot(index=['city','year'], columns = 'attribute', values='value')
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try `pd.crosstab(
    [df["CITY"], df["YEAR"]], df["ATTRIBUTE"], values=df["VALUE"], aggfunc=lambda x: x
)` it would help if u showed the actual dataframe u wanted instead of a list of flat columns

Comment: Your sample `city - year - population - crime - median_income- etc....` , is this your column header, or what? Please provide a sample of columns and a few rows of what you want it to look like. And how do you mean "it doesn't work"? Please provide example of what the output was, because that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """city-year-attribute-value
dallas-2002-crime-100
dallas-2003-crime-101
dallas-2002-population-4000
houston-2002-population-4100"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="-")

pivoted = df.pivot_table(
    index=["city", "year"],
    columns=["attribute"],
    values=["value"]
)
print(pivoted.reset_index())
```

Result:

```
              city  year  value           
attribute                 crime population
0           dallas  2002  100.0     4000.0
1           dallas  2003  101.0        NaN
2          houston  2002    NaN     4100.0
```